# AS3: Sprite does not dispatch mouse event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sprite

I am new to as3. I have developed a small application which in as3. But issue is the sprite  created does not dispatch any mouse events [ eg: click  ]. Please can anyone guide me and throw some comment

```
   .... private var progressBarHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();
        progressBarHolder.graphics.clear();
        progressBarHolder.graphics.beginFill(0xeaeaea); 
        progressBarHolder.alpha  = 0.5;
        progressBarHolder.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 80, 25, 0,0); 
        //progressBarHolder.graphics.endFill();
        progressBarHolder.width = progressBarWidth; 
        progressBarHolder.height = 24;
        progressBarHolder.x = 48;
        progressBarHolder.y = _videoModule.getHeight() - 48;
        progressBarHolder.buttonMode = true;
        progressBarHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, progressBarHolderClick);
        _overlay.addChild(progressBarHolder);
        .....
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your `progressBarHolderClick` function ?

Comment: @anu Could you show us your `progressBarHolderClick` function?

Comment: How are you determining that it is not dispatching the event?  You click on what is obviously the object and nothing happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks ok, possible problems:

- width and height of your sprite are not zero (progressBarWidth != 0)
- mouse is enabled on parent (_overlay), to make sure use - 
  *progressBarHolder.mouseEnabled = true;*
- make sure there is nothing above progressBarHolder on the Z index that is blocking the click from the sprite.

Comment: Thanks! it was a z-index issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Look up on `_overlay` or `progressBarHolderClick` listener. Also It's can happens if property `mouseChildren` of `_overlay` or other parent set as `false`.

Show more code if you still can't find solution.